# svg animation wont play again after clicking

Tags: jquery, css, svg, jquery-animate, keyframe

hello i have [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KiarashZ/gms6jzg9/1/)

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 $('#sa').addClass('animate-sa2')
})
```

```css
   .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:33;stroke-miterlimit:10;};
    #sa{
   stroke-dasharray:320;
   stroke-dashoffset:100;
   }
     .animate-sa{
       animation:1.5s animate-sa forwards;
      }
        .animate-sa-2{
       animation:1.5s animate-sa forwards;
      }
       @keyframes animate-sa{
  from{
    stroke-dasharray:320;
    stroke-dashoffset:100;
   }
   to{
    stroke-dasharray:500;
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
   }
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">click</button>

    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"         x="0px" y="0px" width="501.9px" height="273.8px" viewBox="0 0 501.9 273.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 501.9     273.8;" xml:space="preserve">
    
    
                <path  id="sa" class="animate-sa st0 " d="M281,156.2c56,51.5,80.4-57.4,80.4-57.4c-12.5,41.2-9.2,71,19.2,71.6c28.4,0.6,43.7-71.2,43.7-71.2
                 s-21.2,77.8,32.9,70.8c53.2-6.9,7.6-93.5,7.6-93.5"/>
                  
     </svg>
```

svg  will animate **immediatly on page load** because of class **("animate-sa")**, but i have a button here which should animate it again by adding **("animate-sa2)** which is the same as first class. but it doesnt work! could u help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the animation will only run once with that class. To avoid this, you have to remove the class when the animation is complete.

You can find the answer here: https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/

I created a CodePen with my solution:
http://codepen.io/interactivejohn/pen/NpadGy

First we detect the animation event, and then once that event is complete, we remove the class. We remove it first after the initial animation happens on pageload. The next time it runs (after clicking the button), it will add the class and then remove it again.

```
function whichAnimationEvent(){
  var t,
      el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var animations = {
    "animation"      : "animationend",
    "OAnimation"     : "oAnimationEnd",
    "MozAnimation"   : "animationend",
    "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
  }

  for (t in animations){
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
      return animations[t];
    }
  }
}

var animationEvent = whichAnimationEvent();

$("path").one(animationEvent,
              function(event) {
    // Do something when the transition ends
    $(this).removeClass("animate-sa");
});

$("button").click(function(){
  $("path").addClass("animate-sa");
  $("path").one(animationEvent,
              function(event) {
    // Do something when the transition ends
    $(this).removeClass("animate-sa");
  });
});
```